# Error in order(ind) : argument 1 is not a vector

Tags: r

I'm new to coding in R, so bear with me. I'm trying to craft an animated ggplot graph, and it keeps giving me this error; any help is appreciated!

Here's some of myData:

```
                     id                        name is_claimed is_closed       phone review_count
1 nzgC5hhlnSq2DYbJbtH5MQ Foxy's Landing & Restaurant       TRUE     FALSE 16619492284           52
2 i-2aG9_PQBEy7LrsRv0Ivg         Mosman's Steakhouse       TRUE     FALSE 16619487047           63
3 DJoeogRsOW5s9MzgveHQ2A                El Tamarindo       TRUE     FALSE 16617234984           11
4 hwWfv3sSxV3a47UAdSVT5w                      Subway       TRUE     FALSE 16617295564           13
5 TxU0fwF2N2nVhCpzokc1Pg              Little Caesars       TRUE     FALSE 16619456666           54
6 RCOcbYY60L66OYDQR7WUzA                 Vos Pupusas       TRUE     FALSE 16614189575           13
      categories01 categories02 categories03 rating price           transactions zip_code      city
1 breakfast_brunch tradamerican         <NA>    4.0    $$            ['sitdown']    93536 Lancaster
2             bars        steak         <NA>    3.5    $$            ['sitdown']    93536 Lancaster
3       salvadoran         <NA>         <NA>    3.5     $            ['sitdown']    93534 Lancaster
4       sandwiches         <NA>         <NA>    2.5     $ ['delivery', 'pickup']    93535 Lancaster
5            pizza         <NA>         <NA>    1.5     $            ['sitdown']    93534 Lancaster
6       salvadoran   foodtrucks         <NA>    4.0    $$            ['sitdown']    93534 Lancaster
                                                   address
1               ['4555 W Avenue G', 'Lancaster, CA 93536']
2                ['46645 W 60th W', 'Lancaster, CA 93536']
3          ['551 W Ave I', 'Ste E', 'Lancaster, CA 93534']
4      ['1821 W Ave I', 'Unit 103', 'Lancaster, CA 93535']
5 ['1841 W Ave I', 'Bldg 2, Ste D', 'Lancaster, CA 93534']
6                  ['1009 W Ave I', 'Lancaster, CA 93534']
```

Here's my code:

```
library(myData)
    library(ggplot2)
    library(gganimate)
    ggplot(myData, aes(rating, size = log_review_count, color= zip_code)) +
      geom_point() +
      scale_x_log10() +
      theme_bw() +
    labs(title = 'log_review_count: {closest_state}', x = 'review count', y = 'zip code') +
      transition_states(year, transition_length = 1, state_length = 1) +
      ease_aes('linear')
```

Comment: We need to see some or all of `myData` in plain text format (_e.g._ `dput(myData)`) to help. It seems strange that you are using `library` to load your data? Your `ggplot` does not specify both x and y variables, which are required for `geom_point`. And it's not clear what `rating` is.

Comment: how does this look?

Comment: `dput(head(myData))` would be better.

Comment: unfortunately, it would not let me put in the information from dput(head(myData))